# Produce similar embeddings to another model with BERT

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I have a dataset in the form `(input_text, embedding_of_input_text)`, where `embedding_of_input_text` is an embedding of dimension 512 produced by another model (DistilBERT) when given as input `input_text`.

I would like to fine-tune [BERT](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased) on this dataset such that it learns to produce similar embeddings (i.e. a kind of mimicking).

Furthermore, by default BERT returns embeddings of dimension 768, while here `embedding_of_input_text` are embeddings of dimension 512.

Which is the correct way to to that within the HuggingFace library?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the tokenizer of the dataset

and add the neural network to get embedding of dimension 512.

However,what is the meaning of this operation.